# DateTime object and displaying date/time in alternate timezone

Tags: php, oop, datetime

Every question I have read deals with converting a `DateTime` object from one timezone to another and the process is usually the same:

```
$date->setTimezone($newTimezone);
$date->format($format);
$date->setTimezone($oldTimezone);
```

**or** as a batch process, looping through the first two items as necessary, **or** changing `date_default_timezone_set` as necessary.

What I have is a widget that displays times of appointments in multiple timezones and I am finding that I have to either:

- create multiple `DateTime` objects and change each and every one of them when the due date arrives in the widget, or
- use the one `DateTime` object but iterate through each timezone required, actively change it to each timezone, display it, rinse and repeat.

What I am *trying* to do is have ONE `DateTime` object set to the users timezone and never changing it, but displaying it relevant to the other timezones. I know this is not supported out-of-the-bag but how can I best achieve this?

I don't like managing multiple `DateTime` objects, it's simply not needed. What I would prefer is a method like:

```
DateTime::formatForTimezone($format, $timezone)
```

or

```
DateTime::inTimezone($timezone)
```

which I could then use:

```
$date->inTimezone($timezone)->format($format)
```

and `$date`'s timezone would remain unchanged. I could just iterate through the required timezones and the original object would be preserved.

I did write a function to achieve this, but I had forgotten that all objects are passed by reference so that when my function returned the objects timezone had changed which I was required to revert and so the function generated more work (so I scrapped it). But it looked something like:

```
function DateInTimezone(DateTime $date, DateTimeZone $tz, $format){
    $backup = $date->getTimezone();
    $date->setTimezone($tz);
    $output = $date->format($format);
    $date->setTimezone($backup);
    return $output;
}
```

which I have just now made a `class extends`. Basically the same thing, just cutting out one variable.

```
class DateTimeForTimezone extends DateTime {
    public function formatForTimezone($format, DateTimeZone $tz){
        $backup = $this->getTimezone();
        $this->setTimezone($tz);
        $output = $this->format($format);
        $this->setTimezone($backup);
        return $output;
    }
}
```

*I am the first to admit, I don't fully comprehend OOP, any pointers would be helpful*

For example, this does what I'm after:

**CODE:**

```
echo '<pre>';

function p($arg){
    echo "$arg\n";
}
class DateTimeForTimezone extends DateTime {
    public function formatForTimezone($format, DateTimeZone $tz){
        $backup = $this->getTimezone();
        $this->setTimezone($tz);
        $output = $this->format($format);
        $this->setTimezone($backup);
        return $output;
    }
}
$f = "Y-m-d H:i:s A T O e";
$date = new DateTimeForTimezone('now',new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$tzAUS = new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney");
$tzBKK = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok");
$tzLOS = new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

// output ending with '*' should all be UTC
p($date->format($f."*"));
p($date->formatForTimezone($f,$tzLOS));
p($date->format($f."*"));
p($date->formatForTimezone($f,$tzAUS));
p($date->format($f."*"));
p($date->formatForTimezone($f,$tzBKK));
p($date->format($f."*"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2017-09-29 23:37:20 PM UTC +0000 UTC*
2017-09-29 16:37:20 PM PDT -0700 America/Los_Angeles
2017-09-29 23:37:20 PM UTC +0000 UTC*
2017-09-30 09:37:20 AM AEST +1000 Australia/Sydney
2017-09-29 23:37:20 PM UTC +0000 UTC*
2017-09-30 06:37:20 AM +07 +0700 Asia/Bangkok
2017-09-29 23:37:20 PM UTC +0000 UTC*
```

I have achieved my goal but technically the timezone ***is*** changed, it's just reverted back.

Am I just looking at this wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correctly. Zone isn't just about display, it's an integral part of a time's *state*. You can't work with a time value, like "2017-05-13T21:54:00", without knowing its zone. Forget calculations, forget comparisons, until you know the zone. And don't for a minute think that changing the time zone is trivial. It's [notoriously complicated](https://blog.mojotech.com/the-complexity-of-time-data-programming/). So, keep on as you are.

If you want to loop this without managing objects, just do:

```
$date  = new DateTime('2017-05-13T21:54:00', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$zones = [
    new DateTimeZone('Antarctica/Casey'),
    new DateTimeZone('Europe/Helsinki'),
];
foreach ($zones as $zone) {
    echo (clone $date)->setTimezone($zone)->format('c') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[See this live on 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/RNust)

Comment: HANG ON... First things first, I love anything to do with time and I love that link (bookmarked). It reminds me of a Tom Scott video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY ), where he talks about some app he made at one point dealing with time, timezones, daylight savings, varying calendars and leap seconds. Everything in it I knew except for the "leap second smear"!! Good one google!

Comment: HANG ON #2! Now, I actually did read about clone yesterday, but I didn't think of applying it in the main, I was trying to wrap my head around using it in the function and decided I would leave that for the moment. Without realising it, I'd skipped what I've been looking for all along! Working with a clone of the data and changing the timezone is exactly what I wanted AND it's all on one line! Nice, thanks @bishop.

Comment: The only question that raises is the overhead of `clone`. Is it an issue time or memory wise (obviously there's going to be some memory overhead) and should I instead simply change the timezone and change back? I'm thinking it would be one of those "6 of one, half a doz of the other", but clone seems perfect.(And yes, the looping array is the way to go, my example I'd just posted one liners while I was testing, but thanks for the memory prompt)

Comment: As with all things performance, [it's best to measure](https://github.com/phpbench/phpbench) for your specific scenario. What you're effectively testing is the allocation overhead of clone versus the wasted calculation of resetting dates. As PHP 7 is quite efficient at managing objects, I would expect it to fair well. However, even if `clone` comes out ahead, don't forget the garbage collection effect: periodic, non-deterministic slow-down to free-merge blocks. At least with the wasted calculations you're paying all the cost up-front and that might be worth it.